# I am encountering "java.lang.Error" while building a Netlogo extension

Tags: java, netlogo

I am trying to build an extension for Netlogo and am encountering the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

The import org.nlogo cannot be resolved 
 DefaultClassManager cannot be resolved to a type
 PrimitiveManager cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Seems you forgot to add the jar file with that class to the classpath, so go ahead and do that now.

Comment: NetLogo publishes its binaries (jar files) to bintray: https://bintray.com/netlogo/NetLogo-JVM/netlogo  Adding it to your project will depend on your build tool you're using, Maven, sbt, ant or whatever.